# Siesta iOS POST request errors out with "unsupported URL"

Tags: ios, swift, rest, swift2, siesta-swift

I am having trouble with Siesta - an iOS REST Client Framework https://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/.

Below is a simple example of a POST request to a REST API server, which fails with a "unsupported URL" error. Does anybody out there have any experience with Siesta and what could be wrong?

#### Siesta configuration & login server call

```
let api = Service(base: "http://myapidomain.net/rest")

enabledLogCategories = LogCategory.all

let parameters = ["username": "username", "password": "password"]

api.resource(url: "users/login").request(.POST, json: NSDictionary(dictionary: parameters)).success { data in
    debugPrint("success logging in")
}.failure { error in
    debugPrint("failed to log in")
}
```

#### Debug log

```
[Siesta:Configuration] Computing configuration for Siesta.Resource(users/login)[]
[Siesta:Configuration] Applying config 0 [Siesta default response transformers] to Siesta.Resource(users/login)[]
[Siesta:NetworkDetails] Request: 
    headers: (1)
      Content-Type: application/json
[Siesta:Network] POST users/login
[Siesta:Network] – ← POST users/login
[Siesta:NetworkDetails] Raw response headers: –
[Siesta:NetworkDetails] Raw response body: 0 bytes
[Siesta:NetworkDetails] Response after transformer pipeline:  (new data) 
   Failure
     userMessage:    "unsupported URL"
     nsError:        "unsupported URL"
"failed to log in"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Service.resource(url:)` method — the one with the parameter labeled `url:` — expects a complete URL. It looks like you want `Service.resource(_:)`, which takes a path relative to the Service’s base URL.

Try:

```
api.resource("users/login")
```